# Spring Boot Mongo: All collections duplicated across all databases

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a multi-module maven project split up by domains (as in domain-driven design). A requirement is that each domain has its own database. To reduce costs, the decision was made at this stage to keep each database running on a single Mongo server but having its own configuration.

I've included two sample configurations below, but there are a few more.

The issue I'm facing is that all the collections are being created in each database. e.g. the database for Domain A will also have the collections for Domain B, C and D. Domain B will have the collections for A, C and D, and so on.

The data is being persisted to the correct collection, and all the "redundant" collections are empty. I would like to figure out how to resolve this issue so that each database only has the collections for it's associated entities.

## Domain A config

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = {DomainAMongoRepository.class},
        mongoTemplateRef = "domainAMongoTemplate")
@Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DomainADbMongoConfiguration.class)
public class DomainADbConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    private final DomainADbMongoConfiguration mongoConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    public DomainADbConfig(DomainADbMongoConfiguration mongoConfiguration) {
        this.mongoConfiguration = mongoConfiguration;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "domainAMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate domainAMongoTemplate(
            @Qualifier("domainAMongoDbFactory") MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory,
            @Qualifier("domainAMongoConverter") MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter
    ) {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, mongoConverter);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "domainAMongoDbFactory")
    public MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory(
            @Qualifier("domainAMongoClient") MongoClient mongoClient
    ) {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoClient, getDatabaseName());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "domainAMongoConverter")
    public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter() throws Exception {
        MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext =
                mongoMappingContext(customConversions(), mongoManagedTypes());
        mongoMappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(getInitialEntitySet());
        mongoMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet();

        MappingMongoConverter converter =
                new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory()), mongoMappingContext);
        converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        converter.afterPropertiesSet();

        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "domainAMongoClient")
    @Primary
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create(
                MongoClientSettings.builder()
                        .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY)
                        .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(mongoConfiguration.getUri()))
                        .build());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return mongoConfiguration.getDatabase();
    }
}

@ConfigurationProperties("domain-a.mongo")
class DomainADbMongoConfiguration {
    private String database;
    private String uri;

    public String getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
}
```

## Domain B config

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = {DomainBTypeMongoRepository.class, DomainBMongoRepository.class},
        mongoTemplateRef = "domainBMongoTemplate")
@Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DomainBDbMongoConfiguration.class)
public class DomainBDbConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    private final DomainBDbMongoConfiguration mongoConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    public DomainBDbConfig(DomainBDbMongoConfiguration mongoConfiguration) {
        this.mongoConfiguration = mongoConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean(name = "domainBMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate topicMongoTemplate(
            @Qualifier("domainBMongoDbFactory") MongoDatabaseFactory domainBMongoDbFactory,
            @Qualifier("domainBMongoConverter") MappingMongoConverter domainBMongoConverter) {
        log.info("Connecting to Mongo DomainBs db");
        return new MongoTemplate(domainBMongoDbFactory, domainBMongoConverter);
    }

    @Bean(name = "domainBMongoDbFactory")
    public MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory(
            @Qualifier("domainBMongoClient") MongoClient mongoClient) {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(mongoClient, getDatabaseName());
    }

    @Bean(name = "domainBMongoConverter")
    public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter(
            @Qualifier("domainBMongoDbFactory") MongoDatabaseFactory domainBMongoDbFactory) throws Exception {
        MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext =
                mongoMappingContext(customConversions(), mongoManagedTypes());
        mongoMappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(getInitialEntitySet());
        mongoMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet();

        MappingMongoConverter converter =
                new MappingMongoConverter(
                        new DefaultDbRefResolver(domainBMongoDbFactory), mongoMappingContext);
        converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        converter.afterPropertiesSet();

        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "domainBMongoClient")
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create(
                MongoClientSettings.builder()
                        .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY)
                        .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(mongoConfiguration.getUri()))
                        .build());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean autoIndexCreation() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return mongoConfiguration.getDatabase();
    }
}

@ConfigurationProperties("domainBs.mongo")
class DomainBDbMongoConfiguration {
    private String uri;
    private String database;

    public String getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your `@Document` classes have `@Indexed` or `@CompoundIndex`? In that case, try to disable `auto-index-creation`

Comment: If I disable auto-index creation on a new database, it indeed doesn't automatically create all the collections...